# assign the value of SP Library column to local variable in the workflow 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online, office-365

I have the SP Library with User column, Now I want to assign this column in the workflow variable ??
I'm creating a workflow, and need a variable and want to assign the value of library column to that variable.
Thanks Ram.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried  thusfar?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163272.aspx

Comment: Firstly I'm using Reusable Workflow.
I'd created the workflow with designer, Now I have to send email to n number of users and these users are available in the Library column.
So need to access the value of column in the variable.